# How much should battery voltage decrease when headlights turned on (with engine off)

Tags: battery

With a fully charged battery and engine off, I turned on the headlights (+high beams) for about half a minute. The voltage at the battery posts decreased to 12.02V. After turning off the lights it was 12.8V. (I did not record the voltage before the test since it was fresh off the charger.)

Is this normal for a new battery?

EDIT: I found some data:
[Testing Automotive Batteries and Starters](https://www.knowyourparts.com/technical-resources/starting-and-charging/testing-automotive-batteries-starters/)

> Its new battery is rated at 650 CCA and tested at 842 CCA with 3.82m ohms plate impedance.
>   The initial battery voltage was 12.51 volts and at a 50-amp draw, the voltage dropped to 12.15 volts.

I think the (halogen, not LED) headlights (+hi-beam) would only be ~25 amps so I would expect about 0.2V decrease in voltage.

Comment: Seems about normal to me, though I've not tested it directly. The real thing you are looking for is *Does it come back up to full strength after being recharged?*

Comment: When you are talking about fractions of a volt, the battery temperature is significant. We don't know whether it was a hot or cold day when you did the tests! Also when you are talking about mOhms, the resistance of connecting wires etc  is significant. The bottom line is, your battery voltage was stable (not slowly dropping) during a 30 second test, and it recovered quickly to something close to its fully charged voltage (13.2V is a commonly quoted figure). If you had let it recover for an hour or two, the voltage might have been higher than 12.8V.